# Copying and pasting text displayed on tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter interface with a text widget that displays, "ABCDEF". I would like to be able to copy and paste this text using ctrl+c and ctrl+v, respectively. I would also like to prevent any other key from altering the text (backspace, spacebar, basically any key besides ctrl+c and ctrl+v).

To accomplish this task, I tried an approach found here (the very last block of code): https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-make-tkinter-text-widget-read-only/

This code did not allow to copy and paste via the shortcuts. It is shown below. I would like to know how to copy and paste the text displayed by the text widget using the shortcuts, while also not allowing other keys to alter the text. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk


def ctrlEvent(event):
    if 12 == event.state and event.keysym == 'C':
        return
    else:
        return "break"


root = tk.Tk()
readOnlyText = tk.Text(root)
readOnlyText.insert(1.0, "ABCDEF")
readOnlyText.bind("<Key>", lambda e: ctrlEvent(e))
readOnlyText.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A couple of things. First the 'C' should be lowercase. Second, I tested the code by adding a ```print(event.state)``` statement in the ```ctrlEvent``` program and found that ```<ctrl>``` has state number ```4``` not ```12```. So the if statement should be ```if event.state == 4 and event.keysym == 'c':```. I tested the ```event.state``` for ```<ctrl>``` on Linux, I am not sure if it is OS dependent, but some events tend to have OS dependences, so I recommend printing out the ```event.state``` value while pressing ```<ctrl>``` to see which number it should be.

Comment: Also, the function is not actually doing anything other than checking if the ```<ctrl-c>``` event occurs. You need to add the functionality after the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have the code it already does not allow other keys to edit the text box. Below has the detection for `<ctrl-c>` and added a detection for `<ctrl-v>`. It also has the functionality for each.

Use the method `selection_get()` on a text box to get highlighted text from a text box.

Then clear the clipboard and append the desired contents from the text box with `root.clipboard_clear()` and `root.clipboard_append(content)`.

Then retrieve items from the clipboard with `root.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')`.

```
import tkinter as tk


def ctrlEvent(event):
    if event.state == 4 and event.keysym == 'c':
        content = readOnlyText.selection_get()
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(content)
        return "break"
    elif event.state == 4 and event.keysym == 'v':
        readOnlyText.insert('end', root.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD'))
        return "break"
    else:
        return "break"


root = tk.Tk()
readOnlyText = tk.Text(root)
readOnlyText.insert(1.0, "ABCDEF")
readOnlyText.bind("<Key>", lambda e: ctrlEvent(e))
readOnlyText.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that seems to allow copy and paste. However, the text can be altered by any key on the keyboard (e.g., backspace, spacebar etc.). How can I stop such functionalities?

Comment: My mistake, I accidentally left off the part that prevents typing from occuring even though you originally had it in your code. It is the ```return "break"``` and I have edited the answer to include it.

Comment: You need to return "break" for all cases, otherwise duplicate copy of the selected text will be pasted when pressing `ctrl-v`.